# How to convert .html files to .ejs using terminal?

Tags: html, node.js, terminal, ejs

I have some html files that I want to use in a node project. In order to do that I need to first convert them to .ejs files. Is there a set of commands in the terminal I can use to quickly change all the .html files in my directory to .ejs?

Comment: cp HTML-CSS-B.html resetsheet.ejs

Answer (score 1):

You can use unix `find` command for this, with `exec` flag:

```
find . -type f -name "*.html" -exec mv {} '{}.ejs' \;
```

this will rename all the `.html` files in current directory to `.html.ejs`

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is **no**. But that would make a great project for you to work on!

As many people would probably enjoy such a service which is already offered for
[pug/jade](http://html2jade.org/)